# Trouble with Facebook Product Catalog Diagnostics

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I have been trying to get the diagnostics page on my Facebook Product Catalogs page to stop reporting errors for my 'Add to Cart' and 'ViewContent' events.

The errors are as follows:
Missing content_ids parameter
Missing content_type parameter

I was fairly sure that I already had these parameters in place, so I am not sure why I am still being given error messages.

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', '1516478395030244'); // Insert your pixel ID here.

    var lookup = [];
    $('#details-tabs div #details-tab div div div div div.row.sm-margin-bottom-10.xs-margin-bottom-20').each(function(index, value){ 
        var self = this;
        var lastKey = '';
         $(self).find('div').each(function(index, value){
             if(index == 0){
                lastKey = $(this).html();
             } else {
                lookup[lastKey] = $(this).html();
             }
         });
    });
    lookup['address'] = $('.property-details h1').first().html();

    if(lookup['MLS#'] != undefined){
        fbq('track', 'ViewContent', {
              content_name: lookup['address'],
              content_category: lookup['Property Type'],
              content_ids: [lookup['MLS#']],
              content_type: 'product',
              value: lookup['Price Before'],
              currency: 'USD'
         });
    }

    $('.btn-block.fancybox').click(function(){
        fbq('track', 'AddToCart', {
              content_name: lookup['address'],
              content_category: lookup['Property Type'],
              content_ids: [lookup['MLS#']],
              content_type: 'product',
              value: lookup['Price Before'],
              currency: 'USD'
        });
    });

</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1516478395030244&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- DO NOT MODIFY -->
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on why I may be receiving these errors? The tags seem to work as they should on my site.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Best,

Eric M.

Update 5.4.2017:

Here is an example of what my Pixel Helper returns when a 'ViewContent' event occurs:
[FB Pixel Helper Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9ZXE.jpg)

Comment: Have you verified that those variables have the values you think they do? Get the Facebook Pixel Helper Chrome extension, it can show you live what data your pixels are sending.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. I do have the extension and I have posted an image of what the pixel is returning. It looks like my content_type and content_ids are firing correctly, but I am still seeing the error on my diagnostics page.

-Eric M.

Comment: Do you get these errors “live”? Or are you just viewing some kind of dashboard that might show old/outdated data? The "Can’t match products” warning probably still needs fixing if you want your tracking to be accurate.

Comment: Hi @CBroe, these errors are reported directly from the Facebook Product Catalog Diagnostics page, we are not currently using any other dashboard for the dynamic ads. 

And yes, the "Can't Match" is something my team is also working trying to fix. We do have matches, however, so could the errors solely be related to the products that cannot be found in the catalog?

-Eric